# Sript PHP com conexão segura em todas as páginas

Tags: php, criptografia

Desenvolvi um pequeno sistema em PHP que realiza o cadastro de currículos. Hospedei na Hostgator. No plano contratado, tenho direito a um SSL Privado grátis, daí então solicitei a instalação do mesmo em meu domínio. Configure no arquivo htaccess para ele forçar abrir os links com conexão segura (https).

Observei que o carregamento das páginas e dados demoram mais a partir da conexão segura. Quando não utilizava https, abria bem mais rapido. Agora minha dúvida: vale a pena eu manter essa criptografia em meu domínio?  Detalhe: o usuário precisa estar logado para poder realizar o cadastro ou atualização de seu currículo. Ou seja, todos os seus dados só são acessados por um outro painel de uso exclusivo da empresa. A conexão segura realmente deixa o carregamento mais lento? Há alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para tentar melhorar na velocidade?

Comment: Despende do porquê de querer ficar seguro? Que tipo de informação protege? etc...

Comment: Olá Miguel, é um sistema de curriculos. Praticamente todas as paginas são acessadas por meio de login e senha.

Comment: se está dando tanta diferença de velocidade assim, pode ser um problema na sua configuração de redirecionamento, ou falta de cache. SSL é mais lento, mas não é pra dar uma diferença tão grande.

Comment: Olá bacco,  a hostgator que fez a configuração do https. Notei que demora quase o dobro do tempo para carregar as páginas.

Comment: Como as páginas são todas carregadas com informações dinâmicas, isto é, via banco de dados, será que o cache não iria "atrapalhar" um pouco na exibição das informações em tempo real?

Comment: Cache tem que ser feito da maneira correta e das coisas corretas. Você não vai fazer cache de página dinâmica normalmente (a não ser que as informações tenham "validade mínima", mas vai fazer dos scripts e imagens normalmente. Quanto à configuração, não quis dizer do SSL, e sim do seu htaccess e da sua aplicação.

Comment: Olá baco,  meu htaccess eh o mesmo, apenas inclui o comando para forçar a abertura do https. No mais, não fiz mais nenhuma modificação no msm.  Aproveitando a oportunidade, há algo específico que devo considerar neste arquivo em função da minha aplicação rodar em conexão segura?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode mudar muitas coisas para tentar melhorar o desempenho, porém é necessário que tenha acesso ao Root, ou que possa modificar a configuração do Apache ou do NGinx. Como passei a usar o Nginx irei usar como base.

**1. Habilite o keepalive:**

```
keepalive_timeout 100
```

Isso irá manter/criar uma conexão persistente, de curta duração, entre o cliente e o servidor.

Tempo suficiente para que o usuário navegue em ao menos uma proxima página, *isso REDUZ A NECESSIDADE DE handshake*, em outra palavras menos dados (do próprio handshake) são transferidos a cada pagina carregada!

**2. Habilite o cache do SSL:**

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 200m;
```

Uma vez que uma conexão é relizada o Nginx irá armazenar em cache para futuras solicitações, isso irá melhorar em quase 100%. Nesse exemplo o Nginx irá armazenar até 10MB por 200 minutos.

Na [documentação do Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache) é dito que "one megabyte can store about 4000 sessions". Portanto ajuste isso conforme as suas necessidades. ;)

**3. Desabilite o SSL (e habilite o TLS :P)**

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

Isso irá desabilitar o `SSLv2` e o `SSLv3`, reduzindo o número de protocolos tende a melhorar a velocidade dos protocolos habilitados. Mas, não espere uma melhora significativa com isso.

*Vale lembrar que o SSL v2  já é considerado inseguro, portanto desliga-lo é mais do que questão de performance!*

> Navegadores muito antigos (IE6) não suportam o TLS, mas acho que ninguém liga para isso.

**4. Terceirize o trabalho**

Você pode usar produtos de terceiros como [CloudFlare](https://cloudflare.com), [Incapsula](https://incapsula.com), [Sucuri](https://sucuri.net) e [SiteLock](https://www.sitelock.com/truespeed-cdn.php) (nunca usei este!), além de outros serviços de mesmo tipo.

A finalidade deles é de servir como CDN. Eles fazem o proxying do conteúdo do seu site, de quebra ainda podem redirecionar para o HTTPS para você, ou seja o seu servidor não terá o trabalho de redirecionar ao HTTPS. :D

```
Cliente -> [Cloudflare/Incapsula/Sucuri] -> Servidor
```

Por isso tais serviços se encarregam de fazer a entrega o SSL, ao invés de seu próprio servidor. Por isso todo esse cache, com o cliente, será feito pelo CDN.

Mas meu servidor ainda terá que servir o SSL, como isso irá ajudar?

Simples, o CDN nem sempre irá consultar o seu servidor! :)

```
Cliente = Requisição para site.com/img/um_byte.png, site.com/css/css.css...
Cliente -> [Cloudflare/Incapsula/Sucuri]
Cliente <- [Cloudflare/Incapsula/Sucuri]

Cliente = Requisição para site.com/index.php
Cliente -> [Cloudflare/Incapsula/Sucuri] -> Servidor
Cliente <- [Cloudflare/Incapsula/Sucuri] <- Servidor
```

O CDN já possui alguns dos arquivos, o seu servidor poupou 2 requisições e poupou todo o trabalho de processar o SSL de tais duas páginas.

Além disso é possível "falsificar" um SSL, não no sentido literal. Todos esses sites possuem serviço de "SSL Flexível", em outras palavras...

```
Cliente -> {HTTPS} -> [Cloudflare/Incapsula/Sucuri] -> {HTTP} -> Servidor
Cliente <- {HTTPS} <- [Cloudflare/Incapsula/Sucuri] <- {HTTP} <- Servidor
```

> Isso é inseguro! Pois metade do trajeto será usando criptografia, enquanto outra parte não! Mas, se seu objetivo é apenas obter o "cadeado" no navegador, isso será suficiente. Embora eu não considere isso uma solução ética.

> A utilização do "SSL Flexivel", sem que prejudique a segurança de fato, se resume para distribuir imagens, CSS, JS e conteúdo estáticos. Dados desse tipo, na minha opinião, não carregam "nada de mais". Portanto em meus sites tais pastas/domínios usam o Flexível, enquanto o resto (ex. login.php) usa o "SSL Completo", além disso tais conteúdos estão em cache pelo próprio CDN, então não acredito ser um problema de segurança.

O CloudFlare e Incapsula oferecem SSL gratuito, caso habilite o SSL irá usar o certificado gerado por eles.  Para usar o seu próprio certificado *(isso é, usar o certificado que já tem, sem  ser o gerado por eles!)* é preciso desembolsar cerca de 200 dólares/mês no CloudFlare ou 299 dólares/mês no Incapsula ou cerca de 30 dólares/mês no Sucuri. *Não possuo vinculo com tais sites ou serviços aqui mencionados, apenas utilizei todos eles. Os preços podem ser alterados, consulte no site o preço atualizado, assim como os recursos disponibilizados por cada plano.*